Exact sequence of $R$-modules implies sequence of submodules is exact
I'm wondering whether the following problem has unneeded assumptions, or whether there's something about module homomorphisms that I'm missing.
Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $e \in R$ be such that $e^2=e$. For an $R$-module, $M$, denote the submodule $eM=\{e\cdot m: m \in M\}$. If
$$0 \to L \xrightarrow{\alpha} M \xrightarrow{\beta}N \to 0 $$
is an exact sequence, prove that
$$0 \to eL \xrightarrow{\alpha} eM \xrightarrow{\beta} eN \to 0 $$
is also exact.
It seems to me that the assumption $e^2=e$ is unneeded. Restricting $\alpha$ to $eL$, we have that for $l \in L$, $\alpha(el)=e\alpha(l) \in eM$, as $\alpha(l) \in M$. A similar construction applies to $\beta$. Thus, as $\ker(\beta)=\alpha(L)$, it must be that $\ker(\beta \big|_{eM})=\alpha(eL)=e\alpha(L)$, thereby making the above sequence exact. Hence, the assumption that $e^2=e$ was unneeded.

The assumption that $e^2=e$ is needed, an example is the exact sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules:
$$ 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0, $$
and the element $e=2$. Multiplying by $2$ gets the sequence
$$ 0 \to 0 \to \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0 \to 0, $$
which is not exact. The problem is that, if $em \in ker(\beta|_{eM})$ we can conclude that $em \in \alpha(L)$, but not necessarily that $em \in \alpha(eL)$. But if $e^2=e$ then
$$ \beta(em)=0 \implies em = \alpha(l) \implies em = e^2m = \alpha(el) $$
and you're done.

Your assertion about $\ker(\beta|_{eM})$ is unjustified. Certainly, $\ker(\beta|_{eM}) = \ker(\beta)\cap eM = \mathrm{Im}(\alpha)\cap eM$, but the assertion that this must equal $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha|_{eL})$ does not follow.
An easy example is to take a case where $e^2\neq e$, such as $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and $e=2$. Let $L=M=\mathbb{Z}$, $\alpha(a)=2a$, and $N=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with $\beta$ the canonical projection. Then
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z} \stackrel{\alpha}{\to} \mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\beta}{\to}\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\to 0$$
is exact. But the induced maps on
$$0 \to 2\mathbb{Z} \to 2\mathbb{Z} \to 2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})\to 0$$
do not yield an exact sequence, as $2(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is trivial but $\alpha\colon 2\mathbb{Z}\to 2\mathbb{Z}$ given by $\alpha(2k) = 4k$ is not an isomorphism.
You can see that the error is precisely in the assertion about $\ker(\beta|_{eM})$. Here it would be the kernel of the quotient map restricted to $2\mathbb{Z}$, which is all of $2\mathbb{Z}$, but the image of $\alpha|_{2\mathbb{Z}}$ is just $4\mathbb{Z}$.
